# After grunt serve, content of head is duplicated inside the body content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

my issue is the following:
I use grunt to generate my angular project.
So after a grunt build the index in the dist folder is ok with the good structure but after a grunt serve when i look in the consol debug of chrome i see the head part is duplicated inside the body part.
Here the following code of index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>XXXXXX</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <meta name="description" content="XXXXXXXXXX">
    <meta name="keywords" lang="fr" content="XXXXXXX">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <!-- include: "type": "css", "files": ["app.full*.css"] -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--  Google Analytic -->
    <script>
    </script>
    <!--  Google Analytic -->    
    <script>
    </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="XXXXX">
<ui-view></ui-view>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<p class="browsehappy">Votre navigateur est trop ancien.</p>
<![endif]-->
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": ["lib/angular/**/*.js", "lib/angular-translate/**/*.js", "lib/[a-zA-Z]*/**/*.js"] -->
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": ["app.*.js", "js/**/*.module.js", "js/**/*.js"], "ordering": "'top-down'" -->
</body>
</html>
```

And the result inside Chrome debugg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>XXXXXX</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <meta name="description" content="XXXXXXXXXX">
    <meta name="keywords" lang="fr" content="XXXXXXX">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <!-- include: "type": "css", "files": ["app.full*.css"] -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--  Google Analytic -->
    <script>
    </script>
    <!--  Google Analytic -->    
    <script>
    </script>        
</head>
<body ng-app="XXXXX">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>XXXXXX</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <meta name="description" content="XXXXXXXXXX">
    <meta name="keywords" lang="fr" content="XXXXXXX">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <!-- include: "type": "css", "files": ["app.full*.css"] -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--  Google Analytic -->
    <script>
    </script>
    <!--  Google Analytic -->    
    <script>
    </script>
<ui-view></ui-view>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<p class="browsehappy">Votre navigateur est trop ancien.</p>
<![endif]-->
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": ["lib/angular/**/*.js", "lib/angular-translate/**/*.js", "lib/[a-zA-Z]*/**/*.js"] -->
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": ["app.*.js", "js/**/*.module.js", "js/**/*.js"], "ordering": "'top-down'" -->
</body>
</html>
```

So i don't know why its happening.^^

Comment: you need to check gruntfile.js in the project look what task are being executed and which task is running twice which is doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found the answer.
When i declared my app.component i named him body :(.
don't forget to check it.

```
angular
  .module('xxxxFront')
  .component('body', {
    templateUrl: 'index.html'
  });
```

so i named it like this.

```
angular
  .module('xxxxFront')
  .component('main', {
    templateUrl: 'index.html'
  });
```